# PostgreSQL datestyle altering

Tags: database, postgresql, date, format

I am busy trying to transfer a PostgreSQL database however I noticed that when I do a backup export of the PostgreSQL database it outputs the dates as Y/m/d.

I did the set datestyle = 'ISO, DMY' previously and when I do inserts I can insert the date as DMY

```
insert into tablename (datefield)
values ('30-12-2015');
```

which works and to double check I used show datestyle and I did get

```
"ISO, DMY"
```

but when I do a select from the table I see the datetime as

```
'2015-12-30'
```

which it is backing up as so when I try to load it into a database that uses DMY it is failing

Why is this and how I get the data being stored into the database to be DMY so that when I select from a table I see?

```
'30-12-2015'
```

Comment: Afaik you can not change the internal representation of a datefield. But when you query field from a table you can format the output to anything you want.

Comment: The best thing to do is to **not** rely on any format and use ANSI date literals: `date '2015-12-30'`. The format you see, is always applied by the SQL client you are using. It has nothing to do with the way the dates are _stored_. The format yyyy-mm-dd is always identified as ISO style regardless of the datestyle and that's why the export uses that.

Comment: Normally I prefer to stick to timestamps however the task I need to accomplish already has a database using DMY format

Answer (score 0):

It seems I've found the solution, to see the date in the database using the DMY format I had to run

```
set datestyle = 'SQL, DMY'
```

instead of

```
set datestyle = 'ISO, DMY'
```

Comment: Nope, does not work for me in PgAdmin v 4.13

Comment: @kwoxer, are you trying to select the date in a certain format?

Comment: Well maybe it can also be that SHOW datestyle; is not working properly we you run it directly after it. Because internally it changed it I think as now my application is working without datestyle issues.

Comment: @kwoxer i found that it was only really necessary when the data being inserted couldn't be formatted to match the database datestyle, then when selecting the data I just try to stick with using `SELECT TO_CHAR(dateColumn, 'dd/mm/yyyy');`

Comment: Well this is not the best solution. I got this issue on DEV and PROD level. So on DEV I didn't think about the datestyle. But when I run my app on PROD the datstyle on the server postgres was different. So easiest was now to change datestyle on PROD. This was working. But as I said I was confused as the SHOW datestyle was not returning the proper value. I hope this helps someone else in the future. Maybe you try that out. DEV was Windows 10 and PROD ist an Ubuntu 20. Both English languages. :)

Comment: I had a very similar issue before which was the reason I switched over to using Datetime almost exclusively. Mostly because different client databases have the date format for whichever country they're in, gets hard to keep track of. I will definitely try that, maybe I'll try at the application level to add abstraction to the dates to make it more dynamic. Glad you came right though!